# Experiencing delays on Ubuntu startup on an irregular/random basis

Tags: boot

Usually I get about two lines on black screen when I boot up and that only appears for a second or two. [Here is what the dmesg report looks like when I have a rare, instant SSD boot](http://pastebin.com/BaaqAz5i). However, lately I've been experiencing delays that involves me getting delay by at least a minute or longer on the black screen. I've been getting the error 'ata5 comreset failed (errno=-32)' with the time elapsed in seconds preceding it. [This is what the dmesg report looks like in the more lengthy common scenario](http://pastebin.com/e2juLMyB). I am not sure what is going on considering how random the time to boot up would be get shorter or longer. My laptop works fine in performance however, so it is very strange how random these issues are. No, I don't have anything plugged in my laptop when I boot. [Also, here's my fstab in case anyone asks.](http://pastebin.com/eeDwdLnP)

I have laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 with an SSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having an intermittent issue with your CD/DVD drive:

> [    4.657430] ata5: COMRESET failed (errno=-32)
>
> [    4.657491] ata5: reset failed (errno=-32), retrying in 8 secs
>
> [   12.429716] ata5: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
>
> [   14.645801] ata5: COMRESET failed (errno=-32)
>
> [   14.645864] ata5: reset failed (errno=-32), retrying in 8 secs
>
> [   22.750123] ata5: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
>
> [   22.752136] ata5.00: ATAPI: MATSHITADVD-RAM UJ8A7AS, 1.00, max UDMA/100

It could be that the drive does not power up quickly enough (if it only happens on power up, but not on reboot).

It could be that your cable connecting the DVD drive is a bit iffy.

It might be helped with a BIOS update ... or changing a BIOS setting (boot order, power, etc.)

I recommend googling with:   ata comreset failed (errno=-32)

Comment: Yes, I have noticed on reboots (I'm not sure if all of them, I haven't kept track) I get the normal boot time. I thought I had cd drive at the lowest priority but I'll have to check again in an hour or two.

Comment: Okay, I disabled my optical drive in the BIOS, and that seems to have done the trick! After all these years, I also found out that it's the reason my computer makes so much sound! Thanks.